# How to target input fields by incremented ID using For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my goal is to replace text in input fields using my javascript/jquery code. I want to target each input field by incremented ID using a For Loop, but my code is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for(i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    $("#inp"+i).on('change keyup paste input',function(){
        var a=$(this).val();
        var b=a
        .replace(/hey/g,'hello');
        $(this).val(b);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp1">
<input type="text" id="inp2">
```

Comment: huh.. so it was the $(this) keyword I needed. Thanks so much, easily fixed my code!

Comment: @misner3456 do you know why using `$(this)` solves your problem tho?

Comment: @YongQuan yeah I think I sort of get it. $(this) responds to the specific element clicked on